# Simple NSSplitViewController setup appears as thin line, not a window

Tags: xcode, cocoa, storyboard

I'm trying to setup very basic application.

I just created NSSplitViewController. Placed it in storyboard. Put that as Window content. And added a slider on each sub view controller.

The problem is that my app appears as thin line on start up even though I set-up minimal size on window.

Here is what my storyboard setup look like:

[image]

And this is what application looks like after compilation and launch:

[image]

And this line is actually draggable, so when I drag it, my application shows up and I can see both sliders. Is it a bug in XCode or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to set some auto layout constraints on the objects you've put into the two views visible via the Split View Controller.

When I set up a test project just like you have up there, I was also seeing a window with a unmoveable split view divider.

But once I embedded the sliders into their own custom views and set width and heights on that custom view, the window appeared and I was able to move the sliders around.

[image: Split View]

Comment: No you didnt understnad, the line on my second screenshot is the whole application, once I drag it, the window appears.

Comment: did you set auto layout constraints on the items inside each of the views?

Comment: No, what type of constraints I have to set? I've added two more sliders and window showed up... I dont understand that at all

Comment: For each item inside each view, set constraints that define where the items should be placed (e.g. in my example, I set them to be in the very center of each of those views).  That's what causes the views to become initially visible.

Comment: Well while problem went away itself, I think you are kind of right, so I will accept your answer